# Error al llenar un vector y mostrar cada una de sus posiciones (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Tengo una idea pero produce un error, y es que al terminar de escribir los números ingresados en la consola no salen los números después de que encuentra el número "1" en el vector, puede parecer simple, pero no he podido resolverlo ( a no ser que sea el IDE o el pc)

Gracias

```
int vector[50];

cout << "Escriba el Numero" << endl;
for (int i = 0;i <= 50;i++)
{
    cin >> vector[i];
    if (vector[i] ==-1)
    {
        break;
    }

}


cout << "El Numero Completo Es: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= vector[i]; i++)
{
    cout << vector[i];
}
cout << "?" << endl;
```

Comment: Los dos for deben de ser iguales.  El segundo for es incorrecto y deberia de ser igual al primero.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, pásate por el [tour] y, adicionalmente, visita [ask]. Esta pregunta no tiene demasiado sentido tal y como está escrita: con "*despues de que digite "1"*" ¿A qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Pretendes que el programa responda automática en cuanto pulsas un `1`? ¿Has probado a usar el *enter*? ¿Por qué dices de escribir un `1` y en el código buscas el valor `-1`?

Comment: No veo que estés multiplicando nada en tu código ¿te falta algo por añadir?

Comment: @eferion perdón si no me hice entender, la idea es capturar varios números y al dar -1 salga del ciclo ya con los números en el vector que escribió hasta el momento, en el "después de que digite 1" no tiene que dar una respuesta automática, solo tiene que capturar el número, pero no lo hace, ni captura los demás digitos después de ese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a éste error:

[image: ERROR]

Donde se puede ver que evidentemente, desde el `1` deja de mostrar los elementos del vector.

Eso se arregla cambiando la condicional del segundo `for` así:

```cpp
int vector[50];

    cout << "Escriba el Numero" << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i <= 50;i++)
    {
        cin >> vector[i];
        if (vector[i] == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

    }


    cout << "El Numero Completo Es: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; -1 != vector[i]; i++) //<<--aquí cambiamos la
    {                                     //condicional para que se detenga
        cout << vector[i];                //cuando encuentre un -1
    }
    cout << "?" << endl;
```

Como puedes ver, ya no pasa de nuevo el error y muestra todos los elementos dentro del `vector`

[image: Error areglado]

Comment: Si empiezas con "supongo que te refieres" es que la pregunta no está bien redactada, es incompleta o confusa o una mezcla de las tres cosas. En ese caso es preferible no contestar a dar una respuesta que no le sirve a nadie. Por cierto, te sugiero revisar el primer bucle (o a meter 51 números a ver que pasa)